# Swift NSDate Formatter Issue

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter

I am having a strange problem in Swift `NSDateFormatter` with a certain date,

here is my code:

```
let stringDate = "25/03/2015"

let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"

let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(stringDate)
```

This code is working fine and I'm able to get the date from the string. However, if I change the date to "25/03/2016" or "31/03/2017" I'm always getting `nil`.

This is very strange, has anyone also had this problem? Anybody knows what could be the reason behind this strange error?

Comment: Works for me - the source of your issue may be elsewhere in your code. What timezone are you in?

Comment: Are you in a locale and time zone where daylight saving time changes at midnight on those particular dates? Then this could be the reason because 0:00 - 0:59 might not exist.

Comment: @vadian I changed the timezone and it is working now, the strange is that yes I'm in a timezone that has daylight saving time but not on these days, and please put your comment in an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you in a locale and time zone where daylight saving time changes at midnight on those particular dates?

Then this could be the reason because 0:00 - 0:59 might not exist.

Answer (score -1):

I just tried this:

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"

let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString("25/03/2015")
NSLog("%@", date!);

let date1 = dateFormatter.dateFromString("25/03/2016")
NSLog("%@", date1!);

let date2 = dateFormatter.dateFromString("31/03/2017")
NSLog("%@", date2!);
```

And my output was this:

```
2016-03-02 11:31:53.117 SwiftTest[5139:2280171] 2015-03-24 23:00:00 +0000
2016-03-02 11:31:53.117 SwiftTest[5139:2280171] 2016-03-24 23:00:00 +0000
2016-03-02 11:31:53.118 SwiftTest[5139:2280171] 2017-03-30 22:00:00 +0000
```

So it seems something else is wrong in your app.

Comment: I'm testing the code on a "Playground" in a new project, and I'm always getting the same issue, what could be worng?